# Adding API query data to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I'll try to explain it the best way I can. I'm very new to RoR.

I have a Ruby on Rails app, it has only one class and one model that I created using `scaffolding`. The controller is called `countries_controller.rb` it has the following code:

```html
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_country, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @countries = Country.all
  end

  def show
  end

  private

    def set_country
      @country = Country.find(params[:id])
    end

    def country_params
      params.require(:country).permit(:name)
    end

end
```

The model `country.rb` is empty:

```html
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now I created query from an API using HTTParty, and I want to add the results `:name` to the Rails app, so that each result/country will add as a new row in the app. Where to put the code, and how to turn JSON to db entries. I tried `JSON.parse(response)` but couldn't figure it out.

This is my query:

```html
require 'httparty'

response = HTTParty.get('http://api.population.io/1.0/countries/?format=json', format: :json)

countries = response["countries"]

countries.each do |c|
  puts c

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your point  .When you are consuming web service you have to save that in Database so your code will go in model.

Let suppose you have a **countries** table with a **name** field.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'httparty'

    response = HTTParty.get('http://api.population.io/1.0/countries/?format=json', format: :json)

    countries = response["countries"]

    countries.each_with_index do |country|
      country = self.find_by(name: country[i])
        if country == nil
          self.create!(name: country[i])
        end
    end
end
```

Then in controller when you do this

```
 def index
    @countries = Country.all
  end
```

It will give you all the countries name

Comment: Thank you! One more problem. Now every time I load the website it adds the same information to the database. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a different question so post it as a new question but if u insist I am answering it over here

Comment: Thank you very much! Your help is really appreciated!